# chrome extension: how to mute all audio from certain tab

Tags: javascript, audio, google-chrome-extension

I have been searching for something in chrome extension reference to find anything that would allow me to manipulate audio level of a tab. Only option that has come to my mind is make script have it go through all elements in page and either remove them or mute them if possible.

But i feel there has to be a way to reroute all audio streams to nothing, like break them from output which is speakers if using audio api of html5...however no avail either with chrome extension apis or web audio api.

Goal: mute all sounds on page (flash, audio element, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this now, although this will hopefully change in the near-term future.

At the moment, there is nothing in the Chrome APIs, although I did propose a tabaudio API back in February (and am working on a new draft -- as well as an implementation -- right now.)

Can you give me an idea as to what you want this functionality for? (They ask for potential uses when proposing APIs.)

Perhaps the closest that you can do is something similar to what the MuteTab Chrome extension does (written by me, http://www.github.com/jaredsohn/mutetab), which basically scans the page for object, embed, audio, video, and applet tags and hides them from the page.  Unfortunately, this misses web audio.  Also, instead of muting, it "stops" it by removing it from the page, which could block the video or game associated with the sound.  Alternatively, if you just care about HTML5 video or audio or Flash that has an API (such as YouTube), you could could use JavaScript to pause or mute things.

Comment: i had checked out mutetab extension, and its reviews reflect its approach. If i expect audio to be muted then that is far from everything to be removed which this extension does. Use case scenarios YES: 1) i have 25 tabs open and some random things starts playing while i am watching something, i'd like to right click and select mute all other pages. 2) i go to certain site they always have something random starts on its own, i could select to keep this page muted so each time i visit the site its muted.

Comment: 3) i am watching something and some other things on page start making noises i right click on the thing i'm watching and click mute all others. 4) some tabs are open and its making lots of noise, and i am busy and don't feel like stop what i am doing, go onto search mission on that page and bother with it. But i am also not done with that page yet and don't want to close it as i am going to come back to it in 5-10 mins but don't wanna navigate to it again, and or login, etc. So i can right click on tab AND mute it from there. (There isn't a way to add items to right click context menu on tab?)

Comment: MuteTab is intended to cover all of those use cases, but is limited by available APIs.  It does offer a context menu (Chrome extensions can make use of them via https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus), but, again, the functionality is limited by APIs.

Comment: HI, has since the new api been developed?

Comment: I have another application in mind... I'd like to designate certain tabs as "background" tabs (like grooveshark, pandora) .. when audio starts playing in ANY other tab, I'd like to smoothly mute all background tabs temporarily, until the foreground audio finishes.   -- Like the way my car mutes the radio during a bluetooth cellphone call. (honestly, chrome should just do this OOTB) Will this be possible with the new API? We need either audio-sending events, or some way to poll the audio output volume of each tab.

Comment: Any update on this? I'd love to have it available. My use case is that there are a very limited number of websites I go to that I want sound from. Every other website should always be muted unless I specifically unmute it - it is obnoxious for websites to include audio unless they are youtube.

Comment: This is available in canary Chrome now. https://plus.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/YZGhj2uSqjR

Answer (score 1):

There's now a Chrome extension allowing to mute websites by URL using blacklist/whitelist approach called "[Mute Tabs by URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mute-tabs-by-url/bpokcenamldgbghabnklpmbkkcgcgdld)".

It does require you to allow it to read your 'browsing history', but description swears that it doesn't store your URLs anywhere, and event points to a location of source code, so you can verify it for yourself