# Detect if user has muted tab?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Chrome allows users to [mute tabs](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2087960/google-chromes-latest-update-officially-lets-you-mute-noisy-tabs.html), simply by right-clicking them and hitting Mute Tab. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to detect when a user has muted the tab.

To clarify, I'm wondering if there's a way for a website to detect when I've muted their tab.

Comment: no way.  Maybe duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356873/is-it-possible-to-detect-whether-a-browser-tab-is-playing-audio-or-not

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, since it's likely all done internally, but always good to verify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to detect whether a browser tab is playing audio or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356873/is-it-possible-to-detect-whether-a-browser-tab-is-playing-audio-or-not)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, this is not possible in Google Chrome.

Such events can be recorded [using low-level APIs expoosed by Chrome](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/8a331eedfdd5fc06b60f0782a67efb4e3e76b3d8/tools/metrics/ukm/ukm.xml#L4424) but it cannot be done via any of the Web APIs available.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible for JavaScript on websites.

But, browser extensions can detect it using the Tabs API.

Learn more:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-MutedInfo
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/MutedInfo

Comment: I'm asking as a website, not as an extension developer, however, I see my original question was ambiguous, especially with the Chrome tag.

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding. In that case, as far as I know it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but for anyone who may stumble upon this question in the future, according to Mozilla, it is possible to detect if a tab is muted on most web browsers using javascript APIs, if you are able to use install a browser exxtension.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/MutedInfo

Comment: Only available for extensions in most cases: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API