# How to activate the function "Mute tab" in Google Chrome by the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension for Google Chrome.

Chrome has a "Mute tab" function which blocks the sounds from the site. When this function is activated, a "strikeout speaker" icon is shown on the tab.

The task of my extension is to activate this function and to block any sound in this way. How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: So, did you do any research? If this functionality exists, I'm sure it's documented somewhere already.

Comment: Yes, I checked the perfomance of my extension by the other js code. But I do not know the code, which will to change the settings of browser. For example, to click to the "Mute tab" in the context menu of browser's tabs automatically.

Comment: You'll need to use [`chrome.tabs.update(integer tabId, object updateProperties, function callback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update).

Comment: you can view this url for your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356873/is-it-possible-to-detect-whether-a-browser-tab-is-playing-audio-or-not

Comment: Kothari Ankit, Cerbrus, you helped me very much... I am very grateful to you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have learnt, how to do that:

```
 function turn_Off_On_Sound() {
  chrome.tabs.query({url: []}, function (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
      var mutedInfo = tabs[i].mutedInfo;
      if (mutedInfo) chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {"muted": true});
    }
});
```

}